# Find the sum of the series $2^{-\frac{1}{n}} - 2^{-\frac{1}{n+1}}$

Tags: calculus

Find the sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{2^\frac{1}{n}}-\frac{1}{2^\frac{1}{n+1}})$.  Expanding we get
$$(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2^\frac{1}{2}})+(\frac{1}{2^\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{1}{2^\frac{1}{3}})+\cdots+(\frac{1}{2^\frac{1}{n}}-\frac{1}{2^\frac{1}{n+1}}).
$$
Cancelling equal and opposite terms we get $(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2^\frac{1}{n+1}})$. 
If we write it as $\frac{1}{2}-(\frac{1}{2})^\frac{1}{n+1}$, and use $\lim_{n\to\infty} x^\frac{1}{n}=0$, for $|x|<1$, then the answer that we get is $\frac{1}{2}$, but if we take the common factor $\frac{1}{2}$ out, 
then it becomes $\frac{1}{2}(1-(\frac{1}{2})^\frac{-1}{1+1/n})=\frac{1}{2}(1-2^\frac{1}{1+1/n}).$ As $n\to\infty$ it simplifies to $\frac{1}{2}(1-2)=-\frac{1}{2}$ OR as the author has done, $$S_n=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2^\frac{1}{n+1}} \implies \lim_{n\to\infty} S_n=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{1}=-\frac{1}{2}.$$  What is my mistake?

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^{1/n}$ is 1, not zero, isn't it?

Comment: ouch,thanx Gerry, I goofed up in that step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*A CW answer to remove this question from the Unanswered queue.*

---

As [Gerry Myerson remarks](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127585/find-the-sum-of-the-series-2-frac1n-2-frac1n1#comment294473_127585), we have for $0 < x < 1$:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} x^{1/n} = 1$$

Other than that, your computation is correct.